# Df available memory printing

Tags: bash, awk, linux-disk-free

Need a help in printing the **Available** memory in bytes for logical drive below.

When I try printing column **Available** for /dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol00, It is displaying **Available 26%**, where I need **Available 28012413kB**

```
Filesystem          1kB-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol00
                     39426261kB 9378776kB 28012413kB  26% /
/dev/sda1             103513kB   20322kB   77847kB  21% /boot
tmpfs                 525345kB       0kB  525345kB   0% /dev/shm


# df -B KB | awk '{print $4}'
Available

26%
77847kB
525345kB
```

Comment: It seems that the problem you have is with the option given to the `df` command.

Comment: Better specify your OS because `df` is to some extent platform-dependent. Also, it's weird that your `df` chops up a line when a fs path is long. At least that doesn't happen with either BSD or coreutils `df`.

Comment: Also, there's no guarantee that the filesystem field cannot have spaces in it (for instance, my BSD `df` would have things like `map -hosts`), so assuming the fourth field is "available" is unreliable.

Comment: @4ae1e1 - the `/dev/mapper/VolGroup` is an indicator of LVM. Line splitting like this happens for me in Ubuntu 10.04 (the only Linux I can test with at the moment).

Comment: @ghoti Hmm, weird, can't reproduce on vivid with `df` from coreutils 8.23. Does the line splitting happen whenever the field is long, or does this only happen with certain filesystems? Maybe it's a defect in an older `df`?

Comment: Looks like that behaviour changed in version 8.10.  [Check out the comments in the source.](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/df.c#n302) It appears that this was POSIX-compliant behaviour that GNU dropped because it was inconvenient.

Comment: Use `-P` in `df` for POSIX compliant output - `df -P -B KB | awk '{print $4}'`.

Comment: @ghoti Minor nitpick, actually the comment says changed in `v8.10-40-g99679ff` so the change must have been released in 8.11...

Comment: @4ae1e1, I'm a FreeBSD developer, I don't know how you Linux people handle your tags. :)

Comment: @ghoti Well, I'm not a Linux guy either... But isn't that `git describe --long`?

Comment: Ah, indeed it is. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, well, your issue is obviously that you've got a split line.

You can use awk to rejoin lines based on whatever criteria you deem appropriate.  For example, here's something that joins lines in the event that awk comes across a line with only one "word" on it.

```
# df -B KB | awk 'NF==1{old=$0;getline;$0=old FS $0;} {print $4}'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the fields from the end as well

```
... | awk 'NF>3{print $(NF-2)}'
```

should work. I haven't tested though.